# how to determine the action from the stack using the LR parsing tables?

Tags: parsers

I've been having a hard time wrapping my mind around the LR parsing table. Say I have the following table

[image]

given the input action of `id+id*id$`

how does Stack `0E1+6T9*7F10` given input `*$` iproduce action of `R3`?

Comment: You're in state 10 and the input is `$`. Looking across the chart in the row `10` until we find the column `$`, we see `R3`. Why is that confusing?

Comment: okay,  I was looking through the whole trace, what I didn't get was that  for stack `0id5` with the input of `+id * id$`, and action `R6(use GOTO[0,F])`.  then the next stack becomes `0F3`. How is GOTO [0,F] used here? I can update the question if needed.

Comment: GOTO(0,F) is 3, again from looking at the table) which is the new state.

Comment: but how does r6 know which `goto` to pick? it is just arbitrary?

Comment: It uses the non-terminal the reduction creates, and the state on top of the stack after the reduction's right-hand side has been popped. So you need to know what production is being reduced; in this case, production number 6.